# Find out if the OS is running in a virtual environment

Tags: installation, vmware

Is there any way to find out if the OS i'm running (actually installing) is running in a VMWare machine. I need to disable ntp settings if the automated install is done on a virtual machine but keep them enabled if not. VMWare tools are not installed when this check is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 count=$(lshw | grep -i vmware | wc -l) ; if [ "$count" -gt 0 ] ; then echo "disable ntp" ; else echo "enable ntp" ; fi
```

Obviously change the echo's to the commands you want.

Note: this will only work for VMware.  You'll need to make that `grep -i "vmware\|virtualbox\|xen"` or something similar (look at the `lshw` output on virtualbox or xen to see what the exact strings are) if you're using different virtualisation systems.

Comment: May also work to just look at `/proc/cpuinfo` with a similar `grep` statement (less processing than `lshw`).

Comment: @Kees-Cook:  nah, /proc/cpuinfo on my VMware claims to be an Intel Xeon.

Answer (score 0):

For VMWare, the [vmware-checkvm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/vmware-checkvm.1.html) tool can help. It's part of the open-vm-tools package.

Answer (score 0):

Can you determine this post-installation? If so, I'd write a script to run after installing VMware tools and adjust system daemons then. Pre-installation, it could be difficult to come up with a universal solution to the problem.